# Getting ListView height

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a fragment that displays a map and a listview. The map takes up the top (approximately) 2/3 of the view, and the listview takes up the remaining 1/3. I can't seem to access the listview's height after it has been set.

I have called getHeight() on the listview, but it has not yet been set.

Is there an "onListPopulated" method or something that I can use to get the height after it has been set?

I have overridden both oncreate and oncreateview in my fragment, but it hasn't been set by that point yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does a two-pass layout.  The first one defines things, the 2nd actually does the height/width etc.   If you're trying to get the height of a view from with your onCreate() or onCreateView(0 methods, they won't see it as the two passes have not completed while these methods are running. Instead you'll need to do a runnable with a .post on the view like this:

```
    // use post - runnable to get height of view before it's actually shown
    level3Frame.post( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final int halfMargin = level3Frame.getHeight()/2;
            <snip>
        }
    });
```

level3Frame is a view I needed the height of. Creating a runnable on the view's .post  after all the layout has occurred means you can get the height or whatever else you might need from the now fully rendered view.

Comment: Thanks. In what method would you recommend putting this? As you mentioned, oncreate or oncreateview is too early, and I've found onResume is too early as well. IS there some sort of "view is loaded" callback?

Comment: I need to support API level 8 at minimum.

Comment: depends on whether you're using fragments (onCreateView) or not (onCreate)

Comment: I'm using a Fragment, so onCreateView.

Comment: if you like the answer, please select it on the left so I can get credit for it :)